# Selecting from dropdown list using urllib

Tags: python, urllib2, mechanize, urllib

I want to select an item from a drop down list from a `.aspx` page then click a button. Then a table is updated based on the value in the dropdown. When the item in the dropdown is  selected, it will have `selected="selected"` added onto it.

```
<form method="post" action="page.aspx" id="aspnetForm">
    <div id="div1">
        <select name="DropDownList" id="DropDownList1">

            <option selected="selected" value="foo">foo</option>
            ...
            <option value="bar">bar</option>
            <option value="foobar">foobar</option>

        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="Button" value="Submit Value" id="Button1">
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
        <table id="table1" name="Table">
            <tbody>.
                <tr>...</tr>
                ...
                <tr>...</tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

Is there a way to click this select a value in the dropdown, click the button, then get the data in the table using urllib, urllib2, or urllib3? Or will I need to use something like mechanize?

Comment: I would recommend sending a POST request directly, with `DropDownList=` *`item`*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem as yours a little while ago and wrote this little script to do so. I've modified the names to match your example.

```
# Setup
dropdown_id = 'DropDownList1'
button_id = 'Button1'
table_id = 'table1'
browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chromedriver.exe')
browser.get(url)

# Data getting
dropdown = _browser.find_element_by_id(dropdown_id)
for option in dropdown.dropdown.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
    select = Select(browser.find_element_by_id(dropdown_id))
    select.select_by_value(option.text)
    button = browser.find_element_by_id(button_id)
    button.click()
    table = browser.find_element_by_id(table_id)
    html = table.get_attribute('outerHTML')
browser.close()
```

As shown, the html is the html of the table, so you can manipulate using something like Pandas or any other manipulations with that table. Depending on the machine, you may want to add some `sleep` statements to wait for the table load.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend first print the values from html form.

Mechanize has a great structure to fill html forms.

For example:

```
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Read url with Mechanize
url = 'https://example.com/'
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open(url)
# Browser options
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]

for form in br.forms():
    print "Form name: ", form.name
    br.select_form(nr=0) # nr=0 It selects html form without name

    for control in br.form.controls:
        print control
        print "type=%s, name=%s value=%s" % (control.type, control.name, br[control.name])
```

After checking the html form structure with mechanize:

```
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['DropDownList'] = ['InsertValue']
response = br.submit()
search = response.read()
print search
```